Automatically installing .NET 8 as part of WIX V4 installer
I am currently using Wix V4, to install my application which is built on top of .NET 8.
When users install my application, they then have to also download the .NET framework themselves.  I want to make this process easier for them, so its part of my installer.
I currently have Package.wxs, which is in a visual studio project alongside my application. In here I have the following:
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     ... 

  <Package 
      Name="my_app" 
      Manufacturer="my_app.com" 
      Version="0.1.3"
      UpgradeCode="abc-123">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" 
                  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="Main">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="AppComponents" />  /* AppComponents contains all my app files*/
    </Feature>

    <ui:WixUI
    Id="WixUI_InstallDir"
    InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
    />

    <WixVariable
    Id="WixUILicenseRtf"
    Value="license.rtf"
    />
      
  </Package>
</Wix>

Could you help me, be letting me know what I need to do, to also get .NET bundled alongside this? I have tried to follow the documentation, but I find it very confusing and i'm a bit lost.
Thankyou

Not sure about Wix, but if using powershell as a wrapper install script is possible then it can be easily achieved there.
